# Bind: Setting up DLV: named thinks zone records records are out of zone

Tags: bind, named

forward zone file:

```
$TTL 3600;

@ IN SOA ns1.sub.db.archives.net. hostmaster.sub.db.archives.net. (2014112100,4h,1h,7d,1h)

$ORIGIN dlv.isc.org. 
dlv.isc.org. IN DNSKEY 257 3 5 BEAAAAPHMu/5onzrEE7z1egmhg/WPO0+juoZrW3euWEn4MxDCE1+lLy2 brhQv5rN32RKtMzX6Mj70jdzeND4XknW58dnJNPCxn8+jAGl2FZLK8t+ 1uq4W+nnA3qO2+DL+k6BD4mewMLbIYFwe0PG73Te9fZ2kJb56dhgMde5 ymX4BI/oQ+cAK50/xvJv00Frf8kw6ucMTwFlgPe+jnGxPPEmHAte/URk Y62ZfkLoBAADLHQ9IrS2tryAe7mbBZVcOwIeU/Rw/mRx/vwwMCTgNboM QKtUdvNXDrYJDSHZws3xiRXF1Rf+al9UmZfSav/4NWLKjHzpT59k/VSt TDN0YUuWrBNh

$ORIGIN sub.db.archives.net
        IN  NS  ns1.sub.db.archives.net.
        IN  NS  ns1.db.archives.net.

ns1     IN  A   10.103.35.64
luke        IN  A   10.103.35.64
bo      IN  A   10.103.35.65
daisy       IN  A   10.103.35.66
sheriff     IN  A   10.103.35.67
boss        IN  A   10.103.35.68

dlv.sub.db.archives.net. 0 IN TXT "DLV:1:agnznsezdrch"

$INCLUDE Ksub.db.archives.net.+008+21243.key
$INCLUDE Ksub.db.archives.net.+008+23059.key
```

I sign the file with dnssec-signzone command:

dnssec-signzone -l dlv.isc.org -o sub.db.archives.net. -N increment -k Ksub.db.archives.net.+008+23059 sub.db.archives.net.fwd Ksub.db.archives.net.+008+21243

errors from `service named start`:

```
/etc/named/master/sub.db.archives.net.fwd.signed:79: ignoring out-of-zone data (dlv.isc.org)
...
zone sub.db.archives.net/IN: has no NS records
zone sub.db.archives.net/IN: not loaded due to errors.
_default/sub.db.archives.net./IN: bad zone
/etc/named/master/sub.db.archives.net.rev:11: ignoring out-of-zone data (dlv.isc.org)
/etc/named/master/sub.db.archives.net.rev:17: ignoring out-of-zone data (64.sub.db.archives.net)
/etc/named/master/sub.db.archives.net.rev:18: ignoring out-of-zone data 
...
dns_master_load: /etc/named/master/sub.db.archives.net.rev:24: Ksub.db.archives.net.+008+21243.key: file not found
```

I looked at my signed zone file:

```
boss.sub.db.archives.net.dlv.isc.org.   3600 IN A 10.103.35.68
...
```

No wonder it couldn't find the records. But I don't understand why this is happening. I also don't understand how it could be possible to validate a sub network with domain lookaside validation

I did try to validate, pretending the network was a subnetwork of dlv.isc.org, predictably it told be there were no records in the delegate zone.

How am I supposed to do this?

I was following the directions from https://dlv.isc.org/about/using

Comment: Aren't you missing a dot at the end of `$ORIGIN sub.db.archives.net` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a dot at the end of the line

```
$ORIGIN sub.db.archives.net
```

This means that the previous origin is added to the end of that name.

Most "weird" errors in bind can be tracked back to a missing dot somewhere, that's always the first thing I look for when bind is doing unexpected things, after having been bitten by this a couple of times.